# Setting up a gRPC server with. AWS Load Balancer and Ingress

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, grpc, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm working on a side project, and trying to deploy a simple Hello, World! gRPC application on K8s with ALB. I'm having issues reaching my deployed container.

My `deployment.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-grpc-service
  labels:
    app: sample-grpc-service
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-grpc-service
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-grpc-service
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sample-grpc-service
        image: samplegrpcservice
        ports:
          - containerPort: 50051
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 256Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 200m
            memory: 512Mi
```

My `service.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sample-grpc-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: sample-grpc-service
  ports:
    - name: sample-grpc-service
      protocol: TCP
      port: 50051
      targetPort: 50051
```

My `ingress.yaml`

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: "sample-grpc-service-ingress"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/load-balancer-attributes: idle_timeout.timeout_seconds=120
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol-version: GRPC
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-path: /
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/healthcheck-protocol: HTTP
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/success-codes: '12'
  labels:
    app: sample-grpc-private-ingress
spec:
  rules:
    - host: sample-grpc-service.my-domain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: ssl-redirect
              servicePort: use-annotation
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: "sample-grpc-service"
              servicePort: 50051
```

I've followed the guides [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-a-grpc-based-application-on-an-amazon-eks-cluster-and-access-it-with-an-application-load-balancer.html) and [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-support-for-end-to-end-http-2-and-grpc/), and the error I'm getting on the client's side is

```py
_InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNAVAILABLE
    details = "failed to connect to all addresses"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1637251095.787769000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.cc","file_line":3159,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1637251095.787768000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"src/core/lib/transport/error_utils.cc","file_line":147,"grpc_status":14}]}"
```

Which I'm guessing means it can't find the host address. When running `shell` on the running remote container I see that my application is up. When running `ipython` locally on the container I'm able to talk to the gRPC endpoints with `localhost`, so I know someone there is listening...

I've looked in AWS console and the Route53 is in place, I also see the ALB, but the target group is acting weird.. First, the health-check status code is 200 instead of 12, and all it's monitored instances are showing as unhealthy...

Any thoughts, comments, or suggestions are most welcome!

Comment: You have healtcheck-protocol set to "HTTP" but the sucess-code set to 12, which is not a valid HTTP status code. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Thanks @jordanm, but this is what the AWS manual says I should do - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-support-for-end-to-end-http-2-and-grpc/. Do you have another idea on what should be there?

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work?

Comment: @yudhiesh unfortunately no. The POC was dropped. I think you can work around the problem by setting the health check to use HTTP